# kotlin whereNotEqualTo doesn't work for a field that has null value in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: BJ document has a null value of the capital field which should have not taken by whereNotEqualTo]

BJ document has a null value of the capital field which should have not taken by  whereNotEqualTo

```
 val citiesRef = db.collection("cities").whereNotEqualTo("capital", true)
    try {
        val documents = citiesRef.get().await()
        for (document in documents){
            Log.d(TAG,"${document.data}")
        }
    }catch (e:Throwable){
        Log.d(TAG,e.message.toString())
    }
```

This code is not working despite the documentation saying that

> Note that null field values do not match != clauses, because x != null evaluates to undefined.

but after I altered the null value with true or false doesn't matter which one is chosen, the code works well. can somebody explain to me what is the problem I encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following query:

```
val citiesRef = db.collection("cities").whereNotEqualTo("capital", true)
```

It means that you are trying to get all documents in the `cities` collection where the `capital` field holds the **opposite value of the Boolean true**, which is false. So you'll only get the documents where the `capital` field holds the value of false. The above query is the same with:

```
val citiesRef = db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("capital", false)
```

Since null, is not the negation of true, the documents that have the `capital` field set to null, won't be returned. And it makes sense since null is not a boolean type, not a string type, nor any other [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Null represents "none" or "undefined" and it's a distinct data type and cannot be considered "not equal" to any other data type.

That's the same as the docs states:

> Note that **null field values do not match != clauses**

Comment: I am 100% percent agree with you , the query doesn't return null values inside database according to documentation  but my problem there was no document has found even I had some of them that has capital field as not null as you see on pictures after the query has finished the its job. in addition to kotlin sdk I have tried the same query on web sdk and it is worked seamlessly.

Comment: It should work the same way in Android too. I have personally tested and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: thank you for your answer I will check it again